# Bootstrap 4 SASS and ASP.NET5

Tags: sass, asp.net-core, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I want to use bootstrap 4 alpha SASS version with ASP.NET 5 app.
So far I found it is quite difficult to install it and make workflow easy.
They have their Grunt file that creates css and js files and min versions of them, but I can't see a clean way for a good workflow.

What I want to achieve at minimum:

1. Have bootstrap .SCSS/.JS files somewhere in project
2. Whenever I change something in .SCSS and save it should transpile .SCSS into
       .CSS, combine and minify them. Same for JS

Ideally it should work with Browser Link on page generated from .cshtml.
I want to avoid installing Ruby stuff as bootstrap suggests.

So far I tried to use Web Compiler extension, but it doesn't understand bootstrap's SCSS as they do not @import each other.
And gulp or grunt could be used to combine/minify results of Web Compiler, but I don't know how to assign gulp/grunt task on Ctrl+S inside .SCSS event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Grunt (or Gulp for that matter) to compile SASS or LESS is relatively straightforward in Visual Studio once. I have written a guide on how to [compile SASS using Grunt in Visual Studio](http://iambacon.co.uk/blog/getting-started-with-grunt-sass-and-task-runner-explorer-visual-studio)

The main tool you need to run Grunt/Gulp tasks in Visual Studio is [Task Runner Explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708) (shipped with VS2015). This will run your tasks and allow you to do this on compile or on save. Scott Hanselman has a [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx) on this.

Comment: I am leaning towards Gulp also.
There are just so many plugins, that it is quite overwhelming.
Because with Web Essentials you get those warnings regarding vendor specific properties, Web Compiler provides .css and .min.css on save, TypeScript is transpiled with VS, but in the end you need to place it all on  wwwroot and combine, then you need Gulp.

So it is probably easier to write single big Gulp task that does SASS compile, minification, concatenation, autoprefixer and moves it to wwwroot, and just disable all those add-ons :(

Comment: @AndreyBiryulin definitely better in the long run to create your own gulp task. It gives you more flexibility and control over what you are doing. Plus it's then part of the project you don't need a developer to install x,y and z extension to be able to compile.